# Rails Undefined columns methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have strange problem, i have table products with model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :category_id, :name, :barcode, :price, ...
```

but when i run **rails c** i have no access to attributes.

> > product = Product.where("barcode='B0000000008'")

```
  Product Load (22.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [products].* FROM [products] WHERE (barcode=''B0000000008'')'

 => [#<Product id: 8, category_id: 2, name: "Aplikovaná boj. umění (1 hodina)", barcode: "P0000000008", price: #<BigDecimal:362f9c8,'0.95E2',9(36)>, ... ] 

>> product.name
=> "Product"

>> product.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation

>> product.barcode
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `barcode' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003a354c8>>

>> product.id
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003a354c8>>

>> product.price
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `price' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000003a354c8>>
```

but im able to run

```
>> product = Product.new
>> product.name = "xx"
 => "xx" 
>> product.class
 => Product(id: integer, ...)
```

whats difference between Product class and ActiveRecord::Relation class ? How i can get Product class from where method ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `where` returns an ActiveRecord Relation. In simple terms, it is just un-executed Active Record query. You can chain queries like 'order', another 'where', 'joins' etc to this and only when you want to access the records returned by this query will the query be evaluated.

So what you did was

`ActiveRecord::Relation.barcode` which naturally fails.

Anyway, just do `product = Product.where("barcode='B0000000008'").first` and you'll get your product object on which you can call `barcode`